# wpf window start up images

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I would ideally like to keep the resources for a window in a resource dictionary, but am getting stuck as to the best way to make them known before you declare the window.resources section. So I wind up doing something like the code below.

Is there someway to reference the background image brush statically? How can I do better?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
<Window x:Class="Smack.ConstructionAdmin.Presentation.Wpf.Views.ProjectPicker.ProjectPickerView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
...
    Background="{DynamicResource waveBrush}" 
    Icon="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Images/Project_32.png" 
...
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush 
        x:Key="waveBrush" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component\Images\Wave.jpg" 
        />
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your projects Application.xaml file in the [`Application.Resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources.aspx) Section.

Your could also use a standalone Resource File and include it in your windows xaml file or the Application.xaml file.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="{DynamicResource MyBackColor}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Hey, I guess I didn't ask that question very well. Your first snippet is what I am doing now, and what I typically want when different windows use different resources. I *really* meant to ask if I could reference a resource statically instead of dynamically. Can I?